# Create a jar with only one main class and only its dependecies

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have a Java that contains many main classes. I want to create a Jar with only one main class and only its dependencies. I want only the code of the main class and dependencies to be included in the jar. I use Maven to make my jar.

Comment: So you'd like to select one class and build a JAR that contains everything needed to run that one class, regardless of which other classes exist in your Maven project?

Comment: if you use eclipse, it make you life easier. would you be able to use eclipse at all?

Comment: Yes I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The maven way is to have maybe one parent project, and for every application one module project. Every single application project has one Main-Class specified in the META-IBF/MANIFEST.MF, and separate minimal dependencies. Probably need to have one or more library project for internal dependencies.

```
/all
    /lib-a
        pom.xml --> lib-a-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /lib-b
        pom.xml --> lib-b-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /app-m
        pom.xml --> app-m-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    /app-n
        pom.xml --> app-n-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ...
    pom.xml --> all-src-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
            --> all-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The applications generate a manifest with a Main-Class: ... entry.
The dependencies are defined per application.

You might have the idea of having just one project, and a smart maven plugin that handles local dependencies, but why.

You could keep all sources in one project, say generating as artifact a zip with sources.
And every application project could take a specific list of sources from the zip. Hard.

If you indeed want something very customized, I think going back to **ant + ivy** would be more effective.